# Show a record result of a query using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a query that involves two tables to display the records in the view, when modifying that record I use ajax by adding a "Remote True" to the form and adding in the edit action in the controller the "format.Json "and creating an update.js.erb file in which I render my registry after updating it to display it updating the view. My problem is that the record is the result of a query and at the time of rendering it with ajax in the view its not taking the result of the query.

With ajax how could I render the query result?

my index action:

```
@search_liberados = Pedidoliberado.proceso_pedidos_lib.search(search_params)

@search_liberados.sorts = 'Pza desc' if @search_liberados.sorts.empty?
@pedidosliberados = @search_liberados.result().page(params[:pedidosliberados]).per(15)
```

this is my view

```
  <tbody id="container_pedidosliberados">
            <%= render @pedidosliberados %><!--carga todos los productos-->
  </tbody>
```

my partial _pedidoliberado:

```
<tr id="pedidoliberado_<%= pedidoliberado.id %>">
  <td class="component_name_body_col"><%=pedidoliberado.TOTAL%></td>
  <td class="component_name_body_col">
    <%= form_for(pedidoliberado, :method => :put, remote: true, :url => {:controller =>'pedidosliberados', :action => 'update', :id => pedidoliberado.ID}, html: {class: "form-horizontal "}) do |f| %><!--ajax-->

      <%= f.hidden_field :STATUS %>

        <%= submit_tag "save", class: "btn btn-primary Entregar", data: { disable_with: 'Actualizando' }%>

    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

my query:

```
  def self.proceso_pedidos_lib
    query = select("[pedidosliberados].PEDIDO AS Pedido, SUM([detalle].IMPORTE) AS IMPORTE, SUM([detalle].IVA) AS IVA, SUM([detalle].IMPORTE) + SUM([detalle].IVA) AS TOTAL")
            .joins('inner join detalle ON pedidosliberados.PEDIDO = detalle.PEDIDO ')
    query
  end
```

my edit action:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pedidoliberado.update(pedidoliberado_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pedidoliberado, notice: 'Pedidoliberado was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pedidoliberado }
        format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'saved.'} #ajax
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @pedidoliberado.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'Error.'} #ajax
      end
    end
  end
```

my update.js.erb:

```
$("#pedidoliberado_<%= @pedidoliberado.id %>").fadeOut(500, function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $("#container_pedidosliberados").prepend('<%= j render @pedidoliberado %>');

});
$("#notice").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partials/flash' , :locals => { :flash => flash }).html_safe %>");

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#notice').fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(this).create();
  })
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Did you try by removing the format.html line in your edit action?

Comment: @VineethSubbaraya thanks for answer, yes I did but  it still shows me the record without the result of the query

Comment: Can you please explain what the search function is doing in the index action? did you mean to put it there?

Comment: @VineethSubbaraya the Search function is simply the use of gems kaminari and ransack for pagination and search, they work fine

Comment: Can you also please check if you are getting any errors on your browser console? And try using pry debugger to check whether your function is returning you  the right results

Comment: @VineethSubbaraya yes I getting this error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `TOTAL' for #<Pedidoliberado:0x86a65fa0> because that column was created in the query

Comment: You should use "@pedidosliberados" to be available in your view file. And please check the result of your query because it seems that "TOTAL" is not available.

Comment: So I have "@pedidosliberados" in the view, when I load the page the query works because it shows me the data, but the problem is that when I modify the registry and show it by ajax using update.js.erb then it is not printing my record of the result Of the query that uses an inner join with another table but it is printing only without the query, showing only the data that are of the table "orders released" and the others that were created in the query does not show them because apparently it is not doing Use the query in ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the query in your update action. The queried parameters won't be available unless you run it in your update action. Also you have written a class method which won't be available for instance(individual record)

```
def self.proceso_pedidos_lib
    query = select("[pedidosliberados].PEDIDO AS Pedido, SUM([detalle].IMPORTE) AS IMPORTE, SUM([detalle].IVA) AS IVA, SUM([detalle].IMPORTE) + SUM([detalle].IVA) AS TOTAL")
        .joins('inner join detalle ON pedidosliberados.PEDIDO = detalle.PEDIDO ')
    query
end
```

You would have to run this below command to get join fields like IMPORTE and such.

```
  @pedidoliberado.proceso_pedidos_lib
```

Comment: excelent but with that line is showing all the records of the query again including those already had and had not modified, is there any way to show only the one that modifies?

Comment: After update try running "@pedidoliberado.proceso_pedidos_lib". That should run the query for that particular record.

Comment: woth that line I am getting this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `proceso_pedidos_lib' for #<Pedidoliberado:0x8656b6a8>):

Comment: Since you have written the query as a class method, you cannot call it on an instance. If you remove the keyword self and write it as an instance method you can use it with individual records.